# change appearance of parent based on child

Tags: sass, css-modules

I am trying to alter the with of a parent element if it contains a certain child element. The parent element is two levels up.

I tried in the scss file of the grandchild to use a selector that targets the parent element.

parent `<div class="parent />`

Parent css:

```
.parent {
    flex-basis: 320px;
    min-width: 320px;
}
```

in the .scss file that belongs to the grandchild I use the selector

```
@include breakpoint(dt) {
    .grandchild {
        .parent & {
            flex-basis: 370px;
            min-width: 370px;
        }
    }
}
```

parent width remains unaffected.

Comment: Please be more specific: Show the parent as well as the children, when and how you want to change the width of the child, and ask a question with a question mark.

Comment: I realized that the parent code is within a breakpoint so it probably makes it more specific. Added that to the code example.

Comment: I ended up solving this by toggling a class in javascript instead.

Comment: Good! If you solved it and think it could be useful to others, you can answer your own question for the good of the community. It might help others.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up solving this by toggling a class on the parent using javascript instead.